# Android and Restful services returning json file?

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I am just trying to handle the response from my website restful service, but whenever I execute "httpResponse = httpclient .execute(httpget);" an exception occur and I can't see what is wrong with it since it is restful service, does any one know what is the problem with the following code? many thanks in advance.

```
package com.android.hummedia;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Entity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class searchResultList extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
        int responseCode;
        String message;

        String query = "http://hummedia.byu.edu/mediainfo/search/?title=Harry";

        Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test);
        testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(searchResultList.this, HummediaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        });

        HttpClient httpclient  = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget  = new HttpGet(query);
        HttpResponse httpResponse;


        try {
            httpResponse = httpclient .execute(httpget);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        }

    protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
     } 
}
```

Here is the stack trace found in logCat, thank you:

```
11-08 10:30:02.944: W/System.err(646): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-08 10:30:02.964: W/System.err(646):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
11-08 10:30:02.974: W/System.err(646):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
11-08 10:30:02.984: W/System.err(646):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
11-08 10:30:03.004: W/System.err(646):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
11-08 10:30:03.014: W/System.err(646):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-08 10:30:03.024: W/System.err(646):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-08 10:30:03.045: W/System.err(646):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-08 10:30:03.054: W/System.err(646):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-08 10:30:03.064: W/System.err(646):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-08 10:30:03.074: W/System.err(646):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-08 10:30:03.084: W/System.err(646):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-08 10:30:03.104: W/System.err(646):  at com.android.hummedia.searchResultList.onCreate(searchResultList.java:70)
11-08 10:30:03.114: W/System.err(646):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-08 10:30:03.174: W/System.err(646):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-08 10:30:03.184: W/System.err(646):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
11-08 10:30:03.194: W/System.err(646):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
11-08 10:30:03.215: W/System.err(646):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-08 10:30:03.224: W/System.err(646):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
11-08 10:30:03.234: W/System.err(646):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 10:30:03.244: W/System.err(646):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 10:30:03.254: W/System.err(646):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
11-08 10:30:03.264: W/System.err(646):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 10:30:03.274: W/System.err(646):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 10:30:03.284: W/System.err(646):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-08 10:30:03.294: W/System.err(646):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-08 10:30:03.306: W/System.err(646):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: do you have Internet permission in androidmanifest.xml ?

Comment: We can't see the exception from here.

Comment: Could you give (as Tom says) a stack trace please?

Comment: I do have internet permissions on manifest file: " <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>"

Answer (score 1):

if you are targeting the Honeycomb SDK or above, network operations are disallowed on the main thread.   See **[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)** --

> "The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform
>   a networking operation on its main thread. This is only thrown for
>   applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher"

Use the **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** class to run long-running or network tasks in the background.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

This code (used to send http **post** requests) is what I've used a few times, it may help you...

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.com");
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "value"));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "value"));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "value"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: This wont help, the exception means that a network operation of any sort cannot occur on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the exception tells you everything you need: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

You shouldn't do network stuff in the UI thread and the activity runs there. Try to use a thread or better an `AsyncTask` to do the network calls.

Don't forget you are creating an app on a device that might not have a network connection available or a very slow one. That could result in a call that needs longer than 5 seconds (very common) and will result in an ANR (Application not responding) message and an unresponsive application. More information on the [android page for responsiveness programming](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html).

Answer (score 0):

Write the internet permission above the application tag, see below code`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```